# QuickFixJ:Creating Initiator Settings

Tags: quickfixj

I don't really know much about setting up a FIX connection, but I followed the instructions from [this](https://code.google.com/p/quickfix-messenger/wiki/DevelopersGuide) site exactly. I have gotten to the final point under the "Running from Eclipse" heading and everything has happened exactly as explained in the instructions.

However, now, when I try run the QFixMessenger.java code I am getting the following error:

> 2014-04-01 14:10:32.743 ERROR qfixmessenger.QFixMessenger - Logon
>   failed! quickfix.ConfigError: no initiators in settings   at
>   quickfix.mina.initiator.AbstractSocketInitiator.createSessions(AbstractSocketInitiator.java:173)
>     at
>   quickfix.mina.initiator.AbstractSocketInitiator.createSessionInitiators(AbstractSocketInitiator.java:81)
>     at quickfix.SocketInitiator.initialize(SocketInitiator.java:85)     at
>   quickfix.SocketInitiator.start(SocketInitiator.java:65)   at
>   com.jramoyo.qfixmessenger.QFixMessenger.logon(QFixMessenger.java:315)
>     at
>   com.jramoyo.qfixmessenger.QFixMessenger.main(QFixMessenger.java:146)
>   2014-04-01 14:10:32.956 ERROR ui.QFixMessengerFrame - Unable to parse
>   FIXT 1.1 Dictionary! com.jramoyo.fix.model.parser.FixParsingException:
>   File resources/FIXT11.xml not foud!   at
>   com.jramoyo.qfixmessenger.quickfix.parser.QFixDictionaryParser.parse(QFixDictionaryParser.java:165)
>     at
>   com.jramoyo.qfixmessenger.ui.QFixMessengerFrame.(QFixMessengerFrame.java:287)
>     at
>   com.jramoyo.qfixmessenger.ui.QFixMessengerFrame.(QFixMessengerFrame.java:145)
>     at
>   com.jramoyo.qfixmessenger.ui.QFixMessengerFrame$1Launcher.run(QFixMessengerFrame.java:179)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\FIXT11.xml (The
>   system cannot find the file specified)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101)  at
>   com.jramoyo.qfixmessenger.quickfix.parser.QFixDictionaryParser.parse(QFixDictionaryParser.java:109)
>     ... 17 more

There are quite a few other lines of errors, but I think it might be too much of a mess to upload the whole error message.

Is this a generic error that people get when they first try using FIX and, if so, could someone maybe give me some pointers as to what I should do?

This is what my quickfix.cfg file looks like:

```
[default]
FileStorePath=data/messenger/initiator
FileLogPath=log/initiator
ConnectionType=initiator
SenderCompID=INIT
TargetCompID=ACCEPT
SocketConnectHost=localhost
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SocketConnectPort=9878
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide. To be honest, I'm so lost I'm not even sure what info might be relevant.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: First, you need to specify DataDictionary, such as DataDictionary=path/to/your/FIX44.xml. Or UseDataDictionary=N. Btw, you can supply full error log, it will be useful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Ok, I've added the full error message. I added the file path, but it still isn't working. I've taken a slightly closer look at the code that Ant built and I see that it is reporting errors when trying to import "com.jramoyo.fix42.xml.BodyType". Again, I'm please let me know if this means nothing to you, I am quite out of my depth. It is just generic code that was built when I ran the Ant file from the website, so I'm hoping you might know it. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, i wrote an answer below to better formatting. I am glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

With last edit on error log, we can see first error;

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\FIXT11.xml (The system cannot find the file specified) at
```

Make sure, FIXT11.xml is in yourworkingdirectory/resources/FIXT11.xml.

After solving this issue, write to me results.

By the way, FIXT11.xml ???. Which tutorial you study ?

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the reply. I just did that now, and it eliminated most of the errors. I am however, still getting this one: "quickfix.ConfigError: no initiators in settings". I've taken a closer look by going to the relevant subdirectory and when I clock on the AbstractSocketInitiator.class I get the following error (in Eclipse): "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file AbstactSocketInitiator.class". It looks as though none of the initiator class compiled when I ran the Ant build. Can I download them from somewhere? Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like by logs, source libraries compiled succesfully. quickfix.ConfigError is generic error for most of quickfix language ports implementations. So, something misplaced on config file or code. Maybe, you can share final config file and code that where you created socket initiator.

Comment: That's weird.  You're using FIX42, so you shouldn't need a FIXT11.xml file (that's only for FIX5+).  I'm thinking this is not so much a QF/j problem as a "quickfix-messenger" problem.  I must confess that I don't know anything about the latter.